# Why weren't the police cars in their official colors?

Tags: production, the-hitmans-bodyguard

Recently I watched the movie [**The Hitman's Bodyguard (2017)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1959563/) and was intrigued by the location setting in Europe and especially Amsterdam.

What I noticed as a *local* was that the pattern used on the police vehicles that were in the movie are not similar to the official car pattern used by the Dutch police.

**Movie pattern police vehicle (left)**
[image: The Hitman's Bodyguard movie still displaying car chase with police car]
*Image via [The Hitman's Bodyguard movie website](http://www.thehitmansbodyguard.movie/#/gallery/5/), consulted on October 8th, 2017*

**Dutch police vehicle**
[image: Dutch police vehicle]
*Image via [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dutch_police_VW_Golf.jpg), made by Oxyman, consulted on October 8th, 2017*

I assume they wanted the movie to be as authentic as it could be. Why was the pattern then off? Didn't the Dutch police give permission to use their pattern? What was the reason for this?

Comment: There's plenty more...http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1959563/goofs

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, but I think this one is the most obvious (and gets the most screentime).

Comment: It's the most obvious to a *local* but I doubt the producers cared that much...and, as you say, perhaps the Dutch police were sensitive about it. Some authorities don't allow it..some do.

Comment: Producers often do not care about correct (or even somehow meaningful!) spelling of text in Cyrillic or Asian languages. So why would they care about right colors on a police car... :)